# Flutter Provider dispose method not called when exiting the app

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I am using Provider to wrap MaterialApp in my app, but when closing the app the provider dispose method not called.

My code looks like this:

```
MaterialApp(
  title: 'Flutter Demo',
  theme: ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
  ),
  home: Provider<PageBloc>(
    builder: (context) => PageBloc(FlutterSerialService()),
    child: Consumer<PageBloc>(
      builder: (context, bloc, _) => MainPage(bloc: bloc),
    ),
    dispose: (context, bloc) {
      print("Dispose..");
      bloc.dispose();
    },
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

From the doc of https://github.com/rrousselGit/provider (I guess this is the provider you use!?):

> And in the event where Provider is removed from the widget tree, the instantiated MyComplexClass will be disposed.

So from my understanding the dispose callback is only triggered when you are changing your widget tree. When exiting the app the widget tree still stays unchanged. Did you check if it is called, when you are killing the app?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, killing the app doesn't seems help.
My problem is that I need to dispose the main page bloc when it disposed but I can't get any indication for this. I thought I can use the provider dispose callback.

Comment: What exactly are you doing in the bloc that needs you to dispose it when the page is disposed. From my point of view this does not look like good design...

Comment: The bloc initialize bluetooth communication with some device. I want to close and clean the connection and the steams from it.
You may look the whole code in my repo: https://github.com/moti0375/FlutterBDT

Comment: Have a look at this page: https://flutterbyexample.com/stateful-widget-lifecycle/#9-dispose When using a stateful widget you have the dispose hook available. You can use it for your use case.

Comment: The statful dispose callback doesn't called either! At the beginning, my widget was stateless but then I changed to stateful to use the dispose. It looks like that it's not straight forward the identify that the app is exiting.